# Minesweeper Code

Tags: java, game, minesweeper

I created some code for Minesweeper but I need help going over it. I would like if someone could go over it and point out anything (repeating code, code being called multiple times when not needed, etc).

This it the main class that also does a lot of other things:

```
public class BoardBuild extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static BoardBuild board = new BoardBuild();
    static JPanel p1, p2, p3;
    int miss = 0;

    // top label
    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Minesweeper");

    public static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 10;
    public static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 10;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CELLS = BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH;
    public static final int BOMB_VALUE = 99; 
    public static final int NO_MINE = 0; 

    // all 100 of the board pieces to click
    JButton[][] btn = new JButton[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];

    int mines[][] = new int[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];// board piece values
    private GenerateMines mineGen;
    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");

    public BoardBuild() {
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(lbl1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT));

        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) {
                btn[x][y] = new JButton("");
                btn[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                p2.add(btn[x][y]);
            }
        }
        getMines();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        btnReset.addActionListener(this);
        p3.add(btnReset, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void getMines() {
        mineGen = new GenerateMines();
        System.out.println("New Mine Values Generated");

        // sets indicator according to how many bombs around
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) { 
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) {
                btn[x][y].setText("");
                mines[x][y] = mineGen.getMinePos(x, y);
                if (mines[x][y] >= BOMB_VALUE) 
                    btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.RED);
                else {
                    btn[x][y].setBackground(null);
                    if (mines[x][y] == 1)
                        btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    else if (mines[x][y] == 2)
                        btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    else if (mines[x][y] == 3)
                        btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                    else if (mines[x][y] == 4)
                        btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
                    else if (mines[x][y] == 5)
                        btn[x][y].setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) {
                if (e.getSource() == btn[x][y]) {
                    btn[x][y].removeActionListener(this);
                    if (mines[x][y] >= BOMB_VALUE) {
                        showBoard();
                        return;
                    } else if (mines[x][y] != NO_MINE) {
                        btn[x][y].setText("" + mines[x][y]);
                        btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        miss++;
                    } else if (mines[x][y] == NO_MINE)
                        floodFill(x, y);
                    checkWin();
                    System.out.println(miss);
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnReset) {
            miss = 0;
            System.out.println(miss);
            getMines();
            for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) {
                    btn[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                    btn[x][y].setBackground(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void floodFill(int x, int y) {
        if (x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9) {
            for (int z = 1; z < 6; z++) {
                if (mines[x][y] == z) {
                    miss++;
                    System.out.println(miss);
                    btn[x][y].setText(z + "");
                    btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (mines[x][y] == 0 && btn[x][y].getBackground() != Color.GRAY) {
                miss++;
                System.out.println(miss);
                btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                btn[x][y].removeActionListener(this);
                floodFill(x - 1, y);
                floodFill(x + 1, y);
                floodFill(x, y - 1);
                floodFill(x, y + 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void showBoard() {
        System.out.println("BOOOM");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Unfortunately, You Lose", "",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) {
                btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                if (mines[x][y] != NO_MINE) {
                    if (mines[x][y] >= BOMB_VALUE)
                        btn[x][y].setText("B");
                    else
                        btn[x][y].setText("" + mines[x][y]);
                }
            }
        }
        miss = 0;
    }

    public void checkWin() {
        if (miss == 90) {
            System.out.println("WIN");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulations, You Win!!",
                    "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - 450) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - 500) / 2);

        board.setLocation(x, y);
        board.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        board.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        board.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        board.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        board.setSize(450, 500);
        board.setVisible(true);
        board.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

This is the class which generates the mine positions and the values of the "blocks" around it:

```
public class GenerateMines {
    // all 100 of the board pieces values (0=no bomb near 1=1 bomb near, etc)
    int[][] board = new int[10][10];

    public GenerateMines() {
        int temp;
        int row, column;

        final int NO_MINE = 0;
        final int BOMB_VALUE = 99;
        final int NUM_OF_BLOCKS = 100;
        final int NUM_OF_MINES = 10;

        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_MINES; j++) {
            do {
                temp = (int) (Math.random() * NUM_OF_BLOCKS);
                row = temp / 10;
                column = temp % 10;
            } while (board[row][column] == BOMB_VALUE);
            board[row][column] = BOMB_VALUE;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                if (board[x][y] >= BOMB_VALUE) {
                    if (y != 9)// East
                        board[x][y + 1] += 1;
                    if (y != 0)// West
                        board[x][y - 1] += 1;
                    if (x != 0)// North
                        board[x - 1][y] = board[x - 1][y] + 1;
                    if (x != 9)// South
                        board[x + 1][y] = board[x + 1][y] + 1;
                    if (y != 9 && x != 0)// N.E.
                        board[x - 1][y + 1] += 1;
                    if (x != 0 && y != 0)// N.W.
                        board[x - 1][y - 1] += 1;
                    if (x != 9 && y != 0)// S.W.
                        board[x + 1][y - 1] += 1;
                    if (x != 9 && y != 9)// S.E.
                        board[x + 1][y + 1] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getMinePos(int r, int c) {// sends value of each piece to main
        return (board[r][c]);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could look over this and give me areas which I need to fix.

Comment: The array `mine` is never used in `class GenerateMines`. Consider removing it.

Comment: move `10` as field dimension to a constant. This way you can easily change it in the future.

Comment: My addition from the algorithm perspective - usually, in minesweeper you should generate the mines after the first user click. Why? You just don't want the user to find a mine by the first click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, primitive numeric types all default to their equivalent of `0`, therefore this block can be removed entirely from GenerateMines:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        board[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
```

Additionally, this `Boolean[][] filled = new Boolean[10][10];` is only ever filled as false, and then never read. Therefore these lines can be removed:

```
Boolean[][] filled = new Boolean[10][10];
```

and
     `filled[x][y] = false;`

And a call to `btn[x][y] != null` will produce the same result as checking `filled[x][y]` if you are using it somewhere outside the code you provided.

The `actionPerformed()` method in `BoardBuild` should have an `@Override` annotation as it implements the method `ActionListener.actionPerformed()`.

Your large `if` block in `getMines()` that sets the colour of the JButtons: the value of `mines[x][y]` does not change inside the block, therefore only one can be true in one iteration, and should therefore be an if/else-if block, or a switch statement to avoid checking the condition after it has already found one that is true (in a non-worst case scenario).

The:

```
else {
    return;
}
```

block in `BoardBuild.floodFill()` is unnecessary, as it is the last line in the method and would therefore happen on its own when it gets to the subsequent brace anyway.

In the `BoardBuild()` constructor the call to `getMines();` is possibly dangerous as the method `getMines()` is overridable in a way which would stop the class from constructing properly. The simplest solution is to make the `getMines()` method `private` (if you don't need to use it outside of the class) or `final` if you do.

Although they're more stylistic choices, I like to add `this.` when accessing member variables so you can tell the difference between them and local variables without syntax highlighting, and according to the [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), variables should start with a lowercase letter, so `BoardBuild Board` should be `BoardBuild board` unless you're going to make it final when it'd be `BoardBuild BOARD`.

Additionally, these variables in GenerateMines:

```
int temp;
int row, column;
```

Are only used in the constructor, but stored indefinitely because you made them member variables. They should be local to the constructor. The same is true of `GenerateMines mineGen;` in `BoardBuild` which is only used in `getMines()`. Only make them member variables if necessary to save on memory.

Comment: Additionally, With the amount of time you spend iterating around mines to find out if it's the one that caused events, and changing properties in the same manner, You could cut out a lot of that if you made some kind of MineButton object which has its own ActionListener inside it with the commands to change its own properties? Then each button would work independently and you wouldn't need the global listener to manage it inside the frame.

Comment: what do you mean by create a MineButton object? like all the commands that the program does when you clicks a button?

Comment: @Exikle Basically what C. Ross said except also extending JButton and implementing ActionListener, with the rules for what colour to be in there as well, so each MineButton will have all the methods for what the mine does and how it reacts when you click on it.

Comment: nope, sorry that was by accident, i didnt know it was unaccepeted

Comment: "primitive numeric types all default to their equivalent of 0", except (method) local variables!

Answer (score 5):

The `getMines` method could probably be named more descriptively.  A method that returns `void` with a name starting with "get" is misleading.

You have many "magic numbers" in your code, especially `10` and `100`.  This makes your code less clear, and harder to change.  Consider instead creating constants for board height, board width, and number of cells:

```
public static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 10;
public static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 10;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_CELLS = BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH;
```

So a snippet of code like the below would change to

```
for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {
                btn[x][y].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                if (mines[x][y] != 0) {
```

Or a declaration would change to

```
int board[][] = new int[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT]
```

I'm also not fond of representing the bombs as a magic number.  You could create a cell class:

```
public class Cell { 
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean isBomb;
    private int adjacentBombCount;
    //TODO: Constructors, setters, etc
}
```

Then your code would be much clearer:

```
if (cell.isBomb()){
```

On the other hand, if you want to leave it coded as `int`, you should at least define a constant for the bomb.

```
/*
 *  The value to set if the cell contains a bomb
 */
public static final int BOMB_VALUE = 99;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mines[x][y] == 0
```

seams to mean 'no mine'

I would make a constant

```
final static int NO_MINES=0;
```

=>

```
mines[x][y] == NO_MINES
```